# Changing the value of model is not making any effect

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is `app.js`

```
angular.module('mobApp', ['ionic', 'mobApp.controllers', 'mobApp.services', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('listitems', {
      url: '/listitems',
      templateUrl: 'templates/listitems.html'
    })

  .state('publishmsg/form/new-message', {
      url: '/publishmsg/form/new-message',
      templateUrl: 'templates/publish-msg/publishmsg-form.html',
      controller: 'publishMessageFormController'
  })  

  .state('publishmsg/form/add-tags', {
      url: '/publishmsg/form/add-tags',
      templateUrl: 'templates/publish-msg/publishmsg-form-tags.html',
      controller: 'publishMessageFormController'
  })    

  .state('publishmsg/form/add-location', {
      url: '/publishmsg/form/add-location',
      templateUrl: 'templates/publish-msg/publishmsg-form-location.html',
      controller: 'publishMessageFormController'
  });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/listitems');
});
```

Here is `publishMessageFormController` :

```
angular.module("mobApp.controllers",['ionic','ngTagsInput','google.places'])
.controller("publishMessageFormController",function($scope, $http, $location, $ionicLoading, $cordovaToast, $compile, deviceStatus, $cordovaImagePicker, $ionicHistory){

$scope.testModel = "Hello";

$scope.gotoAddTag = function()
  {
    $scope.testModel = "Hi";
    $location.path('publishmsg/form/add-tags');
  }
```

Here is `publishmsg-form-tags.html`:

```
<ion-view view-title="Add Tags">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <a class="button button-icon icon ion-android-done" href="#" ng-click="tagSelectionDone()"></a>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content class="padding"> 
            <input type="text" ng-model="testModel" />     
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The problem is inside `gotoAddTag()` even after assigning `testModel` to `Hi` the value of text filed is `Hello`

Comment: Do not bind values directly to scope. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a scope hierarchy misunderstanding. You should wrap your model in a parent object so that you ensure the correct key is changed. For example:

```
$scope.model = {
    testModel: 'Hello'
};
```

and then

```
$scope.model.testModel = 'Hi';
```

Basically, the $scope being read and written to is different at both contexts. You can read more here.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes